# How do I redirect from Home to Account View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to navigate from Home page view  to Account page view i.e
from Index page which is in Home view to Register page which is in Account view.

I tried like :

```
 To know more register yourself <%: Html.ActionLink("Register", "Account/Register")%>.
```

But the navigation link is given like

```
http://localhost:5186/Home/Account/Register
```

How do I make it `http://localhost:5186/Account/Register` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Html.ActionLink("Your Link Text", "Register", "Account")
```

First parameter is the link text that'll show, second parameter is the action on the controller, and the third is the name of the controller itself.

Comment: that's true. How did I forget to include the text for the link

Comment: Thanks Brandon which is more efficient to use ?

Comment: @ashuthinks, in terms of efficiency I am not sure. I don't think it'd be noticeable. The main difference is that ActionLink will match the first route it can, while RouteLink lets you target a specific one, which is useful if your routing gets complicated. Other than that, I think it'd just be a matter of which syntax you prefer to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Register", "Account")
```

The 3rd parameter should be the name of the controller

Comment: this is redirected to http://localhost:5186/Home/Account not to 
http://localhost:5186/Account/Register :(

Comment: Yeah. That's exactly what I was thinking. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying RouteLink instead:

```
<%: @Html.RouteLink("Register", new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" }) %>
```